# Linear Transformation Find a which S⊕T=H

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, transformation

how are you? I have a question with this exercise. [image] They ask me to find all the values ​​of  a∈R for which S⊕T=H is:

They give me 4 options:

[image]

I dial {4,-4} but a friend tells me that I am wrong that it is only {-4}. Could you explain why? and who is right hahaha

Comment: $a=4$ does not make $S \oplus T$ a direct sum since then $(4,4,3,16) \in S \cap T \implies S \cap T \ne \{0\}$.

Comment: Did you know the properties of direct sum?